# Chrome won't load jquery or soundcloud api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, soundcloud

I'm trying to build a chrome extension, but for some reason I can't seem to make API requests to SoundCloud or load Jquery.

I know it's because of this:

I will load jquery as such:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in my console, I will recieve

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED 
chrome-extension://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

The same thing happens for the soundcloud api:

```
chrome-extension://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=buskers&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=2
```

Why does `chrome-extension//` keep coming in front of the urls and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to **Content Script Policy (CSP)**, script resource can only be loaded from the extension's package. This will make extensions more secure and ensure that extension will only execute the code you approved.

Solution 1: Download the specific version of jQuery file, include it to your package and then load it into document.

```
<script src="js/jquery.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Solution 2: Actually you can relax the limitation by defining the whitelist of resource origins in manifest file. You could refer to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) for more details if you have a need to load external js file for some reasons.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=buskers&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=2; object-src 'self'"
```

Note:

Whitelisting resource only allow to be loaded over the following protocol: **HTTPS**, **chrome-extension**, and **chrome-extension-resource**. Please use https to load the external library if you want to adopt whitelist solution.

Use whitespace to separate domains form each other if you want to define multiple domains in whitelist.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://domain1.com https://domain2.com;"
```

Comment: And last, but not least, the error is due to the fact that you don't specify the protocol (https). Chrome substitutes for the current protocol and you get that invalid URL.

Comment: But how would I do soundcloud? Would I just add http://api.soundcloud next to ajaz.googleapis.com in content_security_policy

Comment: You can use "whitespace" to define multiple domain in whitelist. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```